# Permanently delete gmail message after some days

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail, schedule

I'm using this script for deleting old messages from gmail every X days.
It functions correctly, however messages are sent to trash.
I want to delete the messages permanently without sending them to trash.
Someone can modify this script?

```
// The name of the Gmail Label that is to be autopurged?
var GMAIL_LABEL = "mylabel";    

// Purge messages automatically after how many days?
var PURGE_AFTER = "21";

function purgeGmail() {

  var age = new Date();  
  age.setDate(age.getDate() - PURGE_AFTER);    

  var purge  = Utilities.formatDate(age, Session.getTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var search = "label:" + GMAIL_LABEL + " before:" + purge;

  // This will create a simple Gmail search 
  // query like label:Newsletters before:10/12/2012

  try {

    // We are processing 100 messages in a batch to prevent script errors.
    // Else it may throw Exceed Maximum Execution Time exception in Apps Script

    var threads = GmailApp.search(search, 0, 100);


    // For large batches, create another time-based trigger that will
    // activate the auto-purge process after 'n' minutes.

//    if (threads.length == 100) {
//      ScriptApp.newTrigger("purgeGmail")
//               .timeBased()
//               .at(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 1000*60*10))
//               .create();
//    }

    // An email thread may have multiple messages and the timestamp of 
    // individual messages can be different.

    for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {
      var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
      for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++) {
        var email = messages[j];       
        if (email.getDate() < age) {
          email.moveToTrash();
        }
      }
    }

  // If the script fails for some reason or catches an exception, 
  // it will simply defer auto-purge until the next day.
  } catch (e) {}

}
```

thanks

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested  in [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty simple all you have to do is get all of your message id's in an array and then use the following two lines.

```
var request={"ids":messageIdArray};
Gmail.Users.Messages.batchDelete(request, "me");
```

You will have to enable the [Advanced Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api)

[batchDelete](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/batchDelete)

So if the rest of your code actually works then this should do it:

```
var GMAIL_LABEL = "mylabel";    
var PURGE_AFTER = "21";
function purgeGmail() {
  var age = new Date();  
  age.setDate(age.getDate() - PURGE_AFTER);    
  var purge  = Utilities.formatDate(age, Session.getTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  var search = "label:" + GMAIL_LABEL + " before:" + purge;
  try {
    var msgA=[];
    for (var i=0; i<threads.length; i++) {
      var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(threads[i]);
      for (var j=0; j<messages.length; j++) {
        var email = messages[j];       
        if (email.getDate() < age) {
          msgA.push(email.getId());  
        }
      }
    }

  } catch (e) {}

}
```

Comment: I not have understanded, I'm newbie in scripts.
I must create a single script with merge two codes you have writed?